# exception when using JSON inside webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services

i'm trying to build a simple web service to connect to a database , retrieve data, put them in json object and sends the a json string that represents the object 
here's the code

i'm using the eclipse webservice wizard , when testing the client I get the following exception
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
and the exception disappears when i remove and JSON object declaration
here is my code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Services {

    public String login(String email,String passwd){
    String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/university";
    Connection connection;
    Statement statement;
    ResultSet resSet;
    //JSONArray resultarr=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject result=new JSONObject();

    boolean gotresult=false;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","");
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        resSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from users where email='"+email+"' and pass='"+passwd+"'");
        while (resSet.next()){
            String fname=resSet.getString(3);
            String lname=resSet.getString(4);
            int rank=resSet.getInt(5);
            int id=resSet.getInt(1);
            result.put("id", id);
            result.put("fname", fname);
            result.put("lname", lname);
            result.put("rank", rank);

            gotresult=true;

        }
        if (!gotresult){
            result.put("error", "user not found");


        } 

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (result.toString());





}
```

}

Comment: Post your exception trace to analyze the issue.

Comment: I'm using the webservice wizard in eclipse , the jsp generated by it just gave me the exception name, and as i mentioned the exception disappears when i delete the json-related code(object declaration and put statements ), is it supposed to throw an exception ???